# Show animation in queue using FFCircularProgressView

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have first tableViewController and second tableViewController. In second tableViewController I download files like this:

```
enum DownloadStatus {
    case none
    case inProgress
    case completed
    case failed
}
struct item {
    var title : String!
    let link = ""
    var downloadStatus : DownloadStatus = .none

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var item = self.items[indexPath.row]
    if item.downloadStatus == .inProgress || item.downloadStatus == .completed {
        print("video already downloaded")
    }
    else {
        let url = URL(string: "link\(indexPath.row + 1)")!
        let downloadManager = DownloadManager()
        downloadManager.identifier = indexPath.row
        downloadManager.tableId = self.tableId
        downloadManager.folderPath = id
        let downloadTaskLocal = downloadManager.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTaskLocal.resume()

        downloadManager.onProgress = { (row, tableId, progress) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                if appDelegate.masterVC == nil {
                    print("master vc is nil")
                    return
                }

                if appDelegate.masterVC.tableId != tableId {
                       // different table
                       return
                }


                let indexpath = IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)
                let cell = appDelegate.masterVC.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath)
                if progress <= 1.0 {

                let progressRing = FFCircularProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(24), height: CGFloat(24)))
                cell?.accessoryView = progressRing
                progressRing.progress = CGFloat(progress)

                if progress == 1.0 {
                    item.downloadStatus = .completed
                    progressRing.circularState = .completed
                }

            }
       }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
   let item = items[indexPath.row]

    if item.downloadStatus == .inProgress {
        let progressRing = FFCircularProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        cell.accessoryView = progressRing
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryView = nil
    }
}
```

This is my `DownloadManager`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension URLSession {
    func getSessionDescription () -> Int {
        // row id
        return Int(self.sessionDescription!)!
    }

    func getDebugDescription () -> Int {
        // table id
        return Int(self.debugDescription)!
    }
}

class DownloadManager : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {



    static var shared = DownloadManager()
    var identifier : Int = -1
    var tableId : Int = -1
    var folderPath : String = ""
    typealias ProgressHandler = (Int, Int, Float) -> ()


    var onProgress : ProgressHandler? {
        didSet {
            if onProgress != nil {
                let _ = activate()
            }
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func activate() -> URLSession {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background.\(NSUUID.init())")

        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        urlSession.sessionDescription = String(identifier)
        urlSession.accessibilityHint = String(tableId)
        return urlSession
    }

    private func calculateProgress(session : URLSession, completionHandler : @escaping (Int, Int, Float) -> ()) {
        session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks, uploads, downloads) in
            let progress = downloads.map({ (task) -> Float in
                if task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {
                    return Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive)
                } else {
                    return 0.0
                }
            })

            print("tbale id \(session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")")
            completionHandler(session.getSessionDescription(), Int(session.accessibilityHint!)!, progress.reduce(0.0, +))
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

        let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/\(folderPath)"))


        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent(String(describing: fileName!))
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
        }catch(let error){
            print(error)
        }



    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            if let onProgress = onProgress {
                calculateProgress(session: session, completionHandler: onProgress)
            }
            let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            debugPrint("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")

        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        debugPrint("Task completed: \(task), error: \(String(describing: error))")
    }

}
```

My files download fine. But when I downloading several files part of them download now and another part state in queue. For files in queue I want to show animation `progressRing.startSpinProgressBackgroundLayer()`. I can show this animation in `didSelectRowAt` but if I back in previous controller and return again in this controller my animation not showing (because I use navigation bar and second tableViewController remove from memory). How to show animation after return in second tableViewController?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a reference to second VC in prepareFoSegue of first VC so second VC won't be deallocated if you will pop from second to first